# Big MySQL database takes time fetching data

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

I have a big messages database there are 2.4m rows:

```
Showing rows 0 - 24 (2455455 total, Query took 0.0006 seconds.)
```

Messages, so I need conversations to load faster, for users that have less conversations it loads (user have 3.2k conversations):

```
 Showing rows 0 - 24 (3266 total, Query took 0.0345 seconds.) [id: 5009666... - 4375619...]
```

For users that have high number of conversations it loads slower (user have 40k conversations):

```
 Showing rows 0 - 24 (40296 total, Query took 5.1763 seconds.) [id: 5021561... - 5015545...]
```

I'm using index keys for these columns:

```
id, to_id, from_id, time, seen
```

Database Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `to_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `from_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `message` longtext NOT NULL,
  `time` double NOT NULL,
  `seen` int(2) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



INSERT INTO `messages` (`id`, `to_id`, `from_id`, `message`, `time`, `seen`) VALUES
(2, 6001, 2, 'Hi there', 1587581995.5222, 1);


ALTER TABLE `messages`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `time_idx` (`time`),
  ADD KEY `from_idx` (`from_id`),
  ADD KEY `to_idx` (`to_id`),
  ADD KEY `seenx` (`seen`),
  ADD KEY `idx` (`id`);


ALTER TABLE `messages`
  MODIFY `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=5021570;
COMMIT;
```

I'm using this query:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  messages,
  (
    SELECT
      MAX(id) as lastid
    FROM
      messages
    WHERE
      (
        messages.to_id = '1' -- ID to compare with (logged in users's ID)
        OR messages.from_id = '1' -- ID to compare with (logged in users's ID)
      )
    GROUP BY
      CONCAT(
        LEAST(messages.to_id, messages.from_id),
        '.',
        GREATEST(messages.to_id, messages.from_id)
      )
  ) as conversations
WHERE
  id = conversations.lastid
ORDER BY
  messages.id DESC
```

I don't know how to make it faster for users that have a lot of conversations, should i re create the database structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notes:

- Use UNION instead of OR (see below)
- There are redundant keys.  The `PRIMARY KEY` is a key, so toss `KEY(id)`
- Don't blindly index every column; instead use the queries to determine what indexes, especially composite indexes, would actually be useful.
- `CONCAT` is unnecessary and possibly counterproductive in `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`.
- Length fields on `INT` are ignored.  What you have is limited to 2 billion values.  (This is overkill for `seen`, which assume is 0 or 1?)
- Use the new syntax: JOIN..ON.
- If `seen` is just true/false, then toss the index on it.  (Or show me the query that you think will benefit from it.)

CONCAT-LEAST-GREATEST -- This is to construct a "friends_id"?  Perhaps you really wanted a "conversation_id"?  Currently, two users can never have more than one "conversation", correct?

Make a new column for `conversation_id` if it is really needed.  (Currently, the `GROUP BY` is inefficient.)  The code below obviates the need for such an id.

```
( SELECT lastid FROM (
    ( SELECT from_id, MAX(id) AS lastid FROM messages
           WHERE to_id = ? GROUP BY from_id )
    UNION DISTINCT
    ( SELECT to_id,   MAX(id) AS lastid FROM messages 
           WHERE from_id = ? GROUP BY to_id )
                     ) AS x
) AS conversations
```

And have these these 'covering' and 'composite' indexes:

```
INDEX(to_id, from_id, id)
INDEX(from_id, to_id, id)
```

and toss KEY(to_id), KEY(from_id) as since my new indexes handle anything else that these were to do.

I think this has the same effect but will run much faster.

Putting it together:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM (
            ( SELECT from_id AS other_id,
                     MAX(id) AS lastid
                  FROM messages
                  WHERE to_id = ? GROUP BY from_id )
            UNION ALL
            ( SELECT to_id AS other_id,
                     MAX(id) AS lastid
                  FROM messages 
                  WHERE from_id = ? GROUP BY to_id )
         ) AS latest
    JOIN  messages  ON messages.id = latest.lastid
    ORDER BY  messages.id DESC
```

(plus the two indexes)

**More**

I was thinking (incorrectly) that `UNION DISTINCT` would replace the need for a `conversation_id`.  But it won't.  Offhand I see some solutions:

- Add a `conversation_id` and dedup using it.  (Meanwhile, I changed `UNION DISTINCT` to `UNION ALL`, making the query a little faster without changing the results.)
- Put the output of my query into a temp table with (from_id, to_id, latestid); then do your `CONCAT-LEAST-GREATEST` trick to dedup conversations; finally do the JOIN back to `messages` to get the rest of the columns.
- That temp table technique makes it easier to write and debug.  My 3rd suggestion is simply cramming the pieces together to do it is a single (hard-to-read) query with Selects nested at 3 levels deep.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, this works much faster faster than ever. but im getting double conversations sometimes. example:
if user=1 messages user=2, then user=2 messages user=1. it shows both as same conversations.

Comment: as you can see on screenshot: https://prnt.sc/-Qn2c-2C2FFg so i want just one if its user=1 messaged user=2 or user=2 messaged user=1 i don't want both to be fetched.

Comment: @Arian - Alas, I goofed.  See my patch.

Comment: Thank you, I'll just add conversation_id that would be easier way. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hey @Rick James, i have another question if i can ask, how can i retrieve last message of sender and receiver ? 
Thank you.

Comment: @Arian - Seems like that was the two `lastid` values in my query.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, maybe you can try adding indexes to your table: [https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/guidelines-for-sql/the-benefits-of-indexing-large-mysql-tables#:~:text=Creating%20Indexes&text=The%20statement%20to%20create%20index,the%20index%20must%20be%20distinct](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/guidelines-for-sql/the-benefits-of-indexing-large-mysql-tables#:%7E:text=Creating%20Indexes&text=The%20statement%20to%20create%20index,the%20index%20must%20be%20distinct).
Make sure to add composed Indexes by rows you are querying.

If that doesn't improve your query time, then the query should be improved.

Comment: Thank you the MySQL Composite Index has make the query faster, now the 40k conversations are loading at 2.5 seconds. is there anything to make it faster?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also partition the message table using the `time` for example.

> Partitioning is a way in which a database (MySQL in this case) splits
> its actual data down into separate tables, but still get treated as a
> single table by the SQL layer. When partitioning in MySQL, it's a good
> idea to find a natural partition key

[https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/07/27/what-is-mysql-partitioning/#:~:text=So%2C%20What%20is%20MySQL%20Partitioning,find%20a%20natural%20partition%20key](https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/07/27/what-is-mysql-partitioning/#:%7E:text=So%2C%20What%20is%20MySQL%20Partitioning,find%20a%20natural%20partition%20key).

Comment: No.  Partitioning will not help performance.  Currently `time` does not play any role in the query; so there is no way for "partition pruning" to come into play.  That is about the only way partitioning can speed up a Select.